# Firebase instance difference when assigning it to a variable

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So let's say I initialized my app like this

```
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

And say I want to get an instance of the firestore database

```
const db = firebaseApp.firestore()
```

What is the difference between that, and this:

```
const db = firebase.firestore()
```

I think it will just give me a new instance, is that right?
If it is a new instance, what is the difference between the first one?
Also if you want to configure the setting of the firestore instance, is it better to do it like this:

```
db.settings(options)
```

Or

```
firebase.firestore().settings(options)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference.  When you call [initializeApp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase#initializeapp), if you don't pass a second parameter giving the app a name, it will work with the default app and return that [App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App) instance.  That's the same default app that's used when you call `firebase.firestore()`.

If you ever want to work with a different app instance, you will have to refer to it by name.

Comment: Can you give me an example why would you use 2 instances? or a reference where I can read more about it?

Comment: Typically, you use two instances when you want to reference two different Firebase projects in the same app.